# layout print in minipage

Tags: minipage

I need to print a page with some information on it and I also liked to print the layout of the page but I don't want it to cover the full page as is usually printed by using the `\layout` command from the layout package. I was thinking of a minipage at the top in the right side. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can try some thing like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{layouts,tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[xshift=-3cm,yshift=-2cm]  at (current page.north east) {%
  \scalebox{0.3}{%
  \vbox{%
    \currentpage
    \pagediagram
    \pagevalues}}};
\end{tikzpicture}

 \lipsum 

\end{document}
```

[image]